# How to create BigDecimal from DoubleBinding

Tags: javafx

How to create `BigDecimal` from `DoubleBinding`

```
private transient ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> sell;

private ObjectProperty<Operation> operation = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> volume = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
```

There is the mistake:

```
 sell = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(new Callable<Double>() {
                Double volumeDouble = volume.get().doubleValue();
                @Override
                public Double call() throws Exception {
                    return (operation.get() == Operation.SELL) ? volumeDouble : 0;
                }
            }, volume, operation);
```

Comment: private transient ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> sell;

Comment: What do you mean by "creating"? Like a method: `BigDecimal someMagicMethod(DoubleBinding binding){ // do the magic }` ?

Comment: sorry casting instead cread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast `ObjectBinding<BigDecimal>` to `ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>`, since the binding class used in this case does not extend `ObjectProperty`. You could bind a `SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>` to an `ObjectBinding<BigDecimal>` tough.

BTW: Note that the `volumeDouble` field in your code snippet is assigned at the time of creating the binding and is never updated based on the volume, even if the `volume` property is modified later.

```
final ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> sell = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
```

```
ObjectBinding<BigDecimal> binding = Bindings.createObjectBinding(new  Callable<BigDecimal>() {
        @Override
        public BigDecimal call() {
            return (operation.get() == Operation.SELL) ? volume.get() : BigDecimal.ZERO;
        }
    }, volume, operation);
sell.bind(binding);
```